# initialising Javascript/Typescript Objects where content 'points to' something initialised by observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am writing an Ionic App using Angular/Typescript.
I have a question which might be a noobie one, so please forgive if so.
I am using a menu page where I have an object 'pages' which is at the top of the file as follows:

```
  pages = [
{
  title: 'Your Dashboard',
  url: 'dashboard',
  utype: [],
  pass: ''
},
{
  title: 'Your Calendar',
  url: 'calendar',
  utype: [],
  pass: ''
},
    ...
      more elements
    ...
{
  title: 'Go to your Business Page',
  url: 'business',
  utype: [AllowedRoles.BusinessStaff, AllowedRoles.BusinessManager, AllowedRoles.BusinessOwnerManager],
  // utype: [AllowedRoles.Admin]
  pass: this.userService.user.BusinessUser.Business
}
```

];

It is the 'pass' reference of the last item I am having issue with. The 'Business' is coming out blank from time to time and I fear I have a timing issue, so, I have put a lot of 'console.logs' into the ngOnInit and this now looks as follows:

```
  ngOnInit() {
  console.log('At Menu');
  this.userService.getUserStore().then((storedUser: UserData) => {
    console.log ('User in menu =');
    console.log(storedUser);
    // this.user = storedUser;
    this.user$ = this.userService.userData$.subscribe( (res) => {
      console.log('Got a result:');
      console.log(res);
      this.userService.user = res;
      console.log(this.pages);         ***<<--this line is logging 'pass' as an EMPTY Business object whereas
      console.log(this.userService.user.BusinessUser.Business);  ***<<--this line has a populated Business.
    },
      error => {
        console.log('Got an error: ' + error);
      });
    console.log(this.pages);
  });
console.log(this.pages);
```

}

I was under the impression, that the 'pass' definition would be a pointer to 'this.userService...Business' but it appears that I am wrong, or is something weird going on?
Does 'pages' get initalised once with real data and hence then not updated?

I can obviously fix this by initialising 'pages' in ngOnInit after the observable updates. But I am genuinely curious, as I feel I have fallen into a trap for the unwary.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its all about object references.

Lets take this example

```
var a = {
    aa: {
        aaa: null
    }
};
var b = {
    bb: a.aa
}
a.aa = {
    aaa: 1
} // modified object ref;
console.log(b.bb); // null
```

Now lets look at other variation

```
var a = {
    aa: {
        aaa: null
    }
};
var b = {
    bb: a.aa
}
a.aa.aaa = 1 // Object ref not modified;
console.log(b.bb); // 1
```

In your case `this.userService.user = res;` this line is causing this effect. 
You are changing reference here.

**EDIT**

You can find page object using `find` and then modify the `pass` property.

```
pages.find(page=>page.url === 'business').pass = this.userService.user.BusinessUser.Business
```

Comment: Ok, I sort of see what you're saying, but can't really see ho I would modify my code to make it more like your 2nd example... 
I also don't really  understand why it behaves this way. I will need to do more research.

Comment: That said, it is late now so maybe some fresh eyes tomorrow 

Comment: You can find and modify property. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I see I could do that. I think though, I might just move the pages initialisation to a function to call after everything is in place. Feels more comfortable somehow. I will do some more research on object references though:)